# Spacing elements in table without edge space

Tags: css, css-tables

How can I space elements in a table in between but with no outer edge spaces.

```
border-collapse:separate; border-spacing:10px;
```

How can I get rid of the 10px along all the edges without using margin:-10px; ?

Comment: Your code is incomplete, post full code! Just CSS is not enough. Post HTML as well

Comment: What things have you tried so far?  Why didn't they work for you, what errors occured?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
td { 
    padding: 10px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Border spacing provides spaces between borders of each cell. [Border Spacing on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing)
What you need is a padding inside of a table cell. Padding gives extra space between the cell border and its contents.

```
td {
    padding: 10px;
    // or...
    padding: 2px 3px 4px 5px; // top, right, bottom, left
}
```

For the explanation on how padding works please check the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding)